# How to store range of keys in cache

Tags: java, caching, memcached, distributed-caching, spymemcached

I am using memcache as my caching framework and it works fine when I have a key value pair in cache server.

My requirement is to store a range of keys with one value. Example: Discount is 10% between Jan 01 1999 to Dec 31 2001. Discount is 15% between Jan 01 2002 to Dec 31 2002. 
User wants to get the value for a specific date like June 10 2000.

How can I store this range of keys in cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing many keys store only one value (under one key) that contains object with information about all ranges. You can use [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html)